# Good (free) Mac OS X Timecard Software

Tags: macos

I am beginning to do some freelance work, and am looking for a good timecard program in Mac OS X. Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [article at the Freelance Switch blog](http://freelanceswitch.com/productivity/6-cool-tools-to-track-your-time/) that lists a few. In the comments, one person mentioned they used [On The Job](http://stuntsoftware.com/onthejob/) (OS X) until they found [SlimTimer](http://slimtimer.com/) (web).

Answer (score 0):

I was just searching for this sort of thing the other day. I found [Paymo](http://www.paymo.biz). It's a web app, but you can download a timekeeper for both OS X and Windows. It has a lot of features such as tracking multiple projects, clients, and tasks. Unlike a lot of other options I found it is completely free for a single user (i.e. freelancers). The only thing you might have to pay for is purchasing more than the 3 free invoices a month.